# How to achieve "continuos randomness"?

Tags: bash, shell-script, random

With `RANDOM%x`one gets a set of discrete results.

How can I achieve following scenario?:
Inside a for loop, I'd like to let a bash script execute command A in 33.33% of all loops and else execute command B (66.66%).

Comment: Why is modulo 3 not adequate?

Comment: What is `RANDOM%x`? I don't have this tool for shell scripts. And what do you mean by continuos?

Comment: Over how small (or large) a sample size do you want to guarantee 1:2 ratio of `A` and `B`? A random number generator could produce `AAA` over three runs; is this acceptable? If you require one `A` and two `B` values in every three runs, it's important to know this before formulating a solution.

Answer (score 2):

For example, to get a decimal random number from the pseudo random number generator (prng) you can use

```
dd bs=1 count=1 if=/dev/urandom 2>/dev/null|od -i|awk '{print $2}'
```

As Michael proposed, you can use modulo 3 on this number, or you can just use

```
let b=`dd bs=1 count=1 if=/dev/urandom 2>/dev/null|od -i|awk '{print $2}'`
if [ $b -ge 85 ]
then B
else A
fi
```

With this you have 33.33% <85 and 66.66% >= 85, so you branch on 85.

As I used `dc` (*the polish reverse notation calculator*) anyway you can of course just use the modulo

```
let b=`dd bs=1 count=1 if=/dev/urandom 2>/dev/null|od -t u1|awk '{print $2" 3%pq"}'|dc`
if [ $b -eq 0 ]
then A
else B
fi
```

Comment: Your first approach (random byte 0..255 less than 85) is approximately correct but your second is not. "To get a number range divisible by 3 you need 3 bytes" is not true. If you add three numbers each uniform random over 0..255 the sum is NOT uniform over 0..767 (or even 0..765, the actual range); the probability it is less-than 256 is only 16.86% and the best approximation to 33.33% is less-than 325. For a start on understanding why see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/431375 .

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was early in the morning. I need two bytes and mask take only the next two bits from the upper one. But that makes it too complex. The modulo 3 version is the best anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You use [`RANDOM`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-RANDOM) [`%`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) `x`, just like you said.

```
if [[ $((RANDOM % 3)) == 0 ]]
then
    A
else
    B
fi
```

⅓ of the time the value modulo 3 will be 0, and then command A is executed. The rest of the time, command B is executed.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not a perfect 1/3 to 2/3 ratio. `RANDOM` generates values 0..32767 inclusive. Modulo 3 gives values in the range 0..2. However, if you modulo 32767 %3 you'll get 1, so values 0 and 1 will have a higher statistical occurrence than 2. (However, for many purposes this will be an insignificant error.)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a random number to get the desired 33% vs 66% results.

Just increase a counter and use the modulo 3 as mentioned by some others before:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0 ca=0  cb=0
while ((count++)); ((count <100)); do
    if [[ $(($count % 3)) == 0 ]]
    then
        ((ca++))
    else
        ((cb++))
    fi
done
printf "count of ca: %d\ncount of cb: %d" ${ca} ${cb}
```

This results in:

```
count of ca: 33
count of cb: 66
```

When a randomizer is used the results are unexpected (not 33% vs 66%):

```
#with a changed if statement:
#if [[ $(($RANDOM % 3)) == 0 ]]
#the results of three runs are:
count of ca: 31
count of cb: 68

count of ca: 27
count of cb: 72

count of ca: 44
count of cb: 55
```

Comment: Your sample size was not large enough for the statistical flattening of 1/3 to 2/3. The output `AAA` is perfectly acceptable for a random number generator, as is `ABB` or even `BBB`.